# p-value of coefficients in glm on categorical count data with a negative binomial distribution interpretation

Tags: generalized-linear-model

Am I correct in thinking that a significant p-value (0.05 for me) for a coefficient in a `glm()` model with a negative binomial distribution means that the input value(s) for that variable are significantly different from the input values of other variables (this is count data)?

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = value ~ Substrate, data = melt_data, init.theta = 0.7020712358, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6955  -0.9492  -0.5596   0.1747   3.7341  

Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                         -1.846e+00  6.390e-01  -2.889 0.003868 ** 
Substrateagarose                    -1.099e+00  1.218e+00  -0.902 0.367025    
Substratealginate                   -1.823e-01  8.036e-01  -0.227 0.820518    
Substratealpha-glucan                1.477e+00  6.557e-01   2.253 0.024251 *  
Substrateamylaceous polysaccharides -1.099e+00  1.218e+00  -0.902 0.367025    
Substratearabinogalactans           -4.055e-01  9.916e-01  -0.409 0.682612    
Substratearibinose                  -1.099e+00  1.218e+00  -0.902 0.367025    
Substratebeta-glucan                 1.576e+00  6.665e-01   2.364 0.018092 *  
Substratebeta-Glucan                 3.401e+00  7.031e-01   4.837 1.32e-06 ***
```

Comment: Is beta-glucan different from beta-Glucan? Just curious if the capitalization matters. If they measure the same thing, then you might have redundant predictors.

Comment: Yeh that is an error on my part, I have corrected it in my version of the GLM :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite right. It suggests your input(s) is statistically different from the *omitted category*, not the "other variables" in the model. Each input/regressor variable is compared with the dropped category (level). And please note this is not specific to a negative binomial model.

According to your output, you entered a discretized version of `Substrate` into your model. R sorts the levels of a categorical variable in alphabetical order. One variable (category) serves as your *reference category*; this category is absorbed into your model intercept. Each category of `Substrate...` (e.g., `_agarose`, `_alginate`, `_alpha-glucan`, etc.) is interpreted relative to the omitted category.

If you want to manually specify the reference level, you can do this by converting `Substrate` into a factor variable and then wrapping it inside of the `relevel()` function. Suppose you want to compare `alginate` with the other eight categories. Here is one way to achieve this:

```
data_melt$Substrate <- relevel(as.factor(data_melt$Substrate), ref = "alginate")
```

Given your output, I assume `Substrate` is a character variable. If you want your dropped category to be less arbitrarily chosen, then converting `Substrate` to a factor variable and manually choosing the referent is a one way to do it.

If you want to avoid modifying the original data frame, then you could also try the following:

```
glm.nb(value ~ relevel(Species, ref = "alginate"), data = data_melt)
```

Re-leveling factors inside of the `glm.nb()` function produces the desired output, but appends the referent label to each variable name. This results in extraneous output. You could also input each category manually (e.g., `value ~ agarose + alginate + alpha-glucan + ...)` to avoid the repeated appending of each `Substrate` level to the variable name. Just make sure you leave out one variable (category) from the specification. Your data appears to be in long format so it may be unwieldy to transform the data frame back into a wide format to facilitate the input of the variables (columns) individually. This suggestion is simply to help you achieve a cleaner output.

In sum, each *category* of `Substrate` is compared with the dropped (omitted) category, which is contained in the model intercept.

Comment: the `emmeans` package is also useful for various comparisons (doesn't require re-fitting the model)

Comment: So if I have understood what you are telling me this model really does not tell me much other that is agarose significantly different from the ommited substrate? How would I produce a statistical test with the type of output I am looking for? This seems to make a glm on catagorical count data pretty useless does it not?

Comment: @Lamma It tells you how each category of substrate is different from that dropped category. You could make multiple comparisons if you so desire. To be clear, *what type of output are you looking for*? I wouldn’t say the model is useless. Do you want to combine categories? Do you want to add more inputs? Do you want to transform your dependent variable? Let me know what you want to do and I can offer further guidance.